# More Pythonistic: prefix subdirectory with parent folder name?

Tags: python, coding-style

I'm doing some folder clean ups.  Given the file structure:

```
a/1
a/2
a/3
a/3/3_1
a/3/3_2
```

I would like to rename the first level folders by prefixing it with the parent folder **ONLY if it doesn't contain any sub directories**, i.e. output:

```
a/a-1
a/a-2
a/3
a/3/3_1
a/3/3_2
```

I've got the following code to do it:

```
root_dir = "./"
parent_path = os.path.abspath(root_dir)
parent_folder_name = os.path.abspath(root_dir).split('/')[-1]

dirs = []
for entry in os.listdir(root_dir):
    absolute_path = parent_path + "/" + entry
    if os.path.isdir(absolute_path) and entry[0] != ".":
        dirs.append(absolute_path)

for first_level_dir in dirs:
    # travers each directory in root directory
    skip_dir = False

    subdirs = os.walk(first_level_dir).next()[1]
    if len(subdirs) == 0
        volume_folder_name = first_level_dir.split("/")[-1]
        new_dir_name = (parent_path + "/" + parent_folder_name + "-" + volume_folder_name)
        os.rename(first_level_dir, new_dir_name)
```

Code works, but seems really verbose. Is there a more **pythonic** way to do this?

Comment: You can remove "if not skip_dir" loop and "skip_dir" variable, For that you have to move code of rename to "if len(subdirs)==0:" loop.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek. I actually took out code that did logging as part of `if len(subdirs) > 0`. Removed the code for SO...

Answer (score 1):

To make the code more readable, extract `has_subdir()` function:

```
from pathlib import Path

def has_subdir(path):
    return any(p.is_dir() for p in path.iterdir())

root = Path().resolve()
dirs = [p for p in root.iterdir() if p.is_dir() and not has_subdir(p)]
for oldpath in dirs:
    newname = '{}-{}'.format(oldpath.parent.name, oldpath.name)
    oldpath.rename(oldpath.with_name(newname))
```